# OpenGL SOIL - Failure to Load Texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, soil

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures) step by step and I even copy-pasted the entire code but it still fails to load the texture. Here's my code, the parts that concern the question:

```cpp
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); // All upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object
                                       // Set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // Set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (usually basic wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
// Set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// Load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
int width, height;
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("container.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind texture when done, so we won't accidentily mess up our texture.
```

And here are my shaders:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main()
{
    color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

And

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    ourColor = color;
    TexCoord = texCoord;
}
```

I'm using SOIL to load image data. Is it too outdated? What should I do?

Comment: What does your project structure look like? The `container.jpg` probably isn't in the root of your project directory.

Comment: check value of **unsigned char* image**

Comment: As Mozfox said: `if (!image) std::cerr << "image load error\n";`

Comment: @vallentin: it's in the root of my project.

Comment: @justus: no image loading error!

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial [code](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/textures) you are following seems to be wrong since it does not call `glActiveTexture` nor `glUniform`. See the [game loop code](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/textures_combined) of the other file at end of the tutorial.

Maybe you are missing something like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture"), 0);
```

Comment: [FYI the LearnOpenGL tutorial **did** include this.](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures)